# React fetched data not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with displaying data using ReactJS.

I am able to fetch the data from the API, and iterate through each object to display each "product". All thirteen (13) products show up on my page, but each item is showing up on a separate page (13 pages in total) instead of showing up on 1 page (does this make sense?). How do I get all "products" to show on one page (in a list) rather than create a new page (with header and footer) for each product?

I am not sure how to better explain this issue. I apologize for the question phrasing.

My code is below:

```
class Top_Sellers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      attributes: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://www.msaironline.com/qa1/api/product.php?type=top")
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let products = data.product.map(pic => {
          console.log(pic);

          let item = 0;

          while (item < pic.length) {
            item++;
          }

          return (
            <div>
              <div className="content-area-container">
                <div className="top-sellers">
                  <h1>TOP SELLERS</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="product_listing">
                    <div className="product_entry">
                      <div className="product-image">
                        <img src={pic.icon} alt="product-placeholder" />
                      </div>

                      <p>{pic.prodID}</p>

                      <div className="product-details">
                        <h4 className="product-title">
                          <a href="/product_pages/prodID409">{pic.prodName}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <h6 className="product-brand-name">{pic.brandName}</h6>
                        <h6 className="product-suggested-retail-price">
                          ${pic.msrp}
                        </h6>
                        <h6 className="product-savings">
                          Savings: <strong>${pic.msrp - pic.prodPrice}</strong>
                        </h6>
                        <h6 className="product-actual-price">
                          <strong>${pic.prodPrice}</strong>
                        </h6>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="FooterLinks1">
                  <HelpAndCurrency />
                </div>

                <div className="FooterLinks2">
                  <AboutLinks />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="about-footer">
                <div className="terms">
                  <p>
                    <a href="/terms" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                      Terms of Use
                    </a>
                    |
                    <a
                      href="/privacy"
                      target="_blank"
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    >
                      Privacy Policy
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div className="copyright">
                  <p>
                    &copy; 2018 - MS Air, Inc. | <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        });

        this.setState({ products: products });
        console.log("state", this.state.products);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container2">
        <div className="container1">{this.state.products}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Top_Sellers;
```

Comment: Just do the network request in `componentDidMount` and use `this.setState({ products: products })` when the request is done. Then derive your JSX from the state in the render method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.product.map` is creating an entire wrapping element for each product.

Map over the products to create a list of `<div className="row">` elements and that should fix it.

I also recommend @Tholle's suggestion about using the state and doing the work in `render` instead of doing everything inside of `componentDidMount`.

Here is a simplified example with the recommended changes:

```
const getData = () => {
  return Promise.resolve([
    { id: '1', name: 'Product 1'},
    { id: '2', name: 'Product 2'},
    { id: '3', name: 'Product 3'}
  ])
}

class Top_Sellers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getData()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ products: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content-area-container">
          <div className="top-sellers">
            <h1>TOP SELLERS</h1>
          </div>
            {this.state.products.map((product) => (
              <div className="row" key={product.id}>
                <h4 className="product-title">
                  <a href="/product_pages/prodID409">{product.name}</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
            ))}
          <div className="FooterLinks1">
            <div>help and currency</div>
          </div>
          <div className="FooterLinks2">
            <div>about links</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="about-footer">
          about footer
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am still pretty new to this... could you show me how I would do that? Any time I move anything in this code it breaks..

Comment: @J.Patterson I added a simplified example, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should split your product into another component. Like this,

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';


const Product = (pic) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="content-area-container">
            <div className="top-sellers">
                <h1>TOP SELLERS</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="product_listing">
                    <div className="product_entry">
                        <div className="product-image">
                            <img
                                src={pic.icon}
                                alt="product-placeholder"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <p>{pic.prodID}</p>

                        <div className="product-details">
                            <h4 className="product-title">
                                <a href="/product_pages/prodID409">
                                    {pic.prodName}
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            <h6 className="product-brand-name">
                                {pic.brandName}
                            </h6>
                            <h6 className="product-suggested-retail-price">
                                ${pic.msrp}
                            </h6>
                            <h6 className="product-savings">
                                Savings:{' '}
                                <strong>
                                    ${pic.msrp -
                                        pic.prodPrice}
                                </strong>
                            </h6>
                            <h6 className="product-actual-price">
                                <strong>
                                    ${pic.prodPrice}
                                </strong>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
class Top_Sellers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            attributes: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://www.msaironline.com/qa1/api/product.php?type=top')
            .then(results => {
                return results.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ products: data.product });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container2">
                <div className="container1">{this.state.products.map(pic => <Product pic={pic} key={pic.prodId}/>)}</div>
                <div className="FooterLinks1">
                    <HelpAndCurrency />
                </div>

                <div className="FooterLinks2">
                    <AboutLinks />
                </div>
                <div className="about-footer">
                    <div className="terms">
                        <p>
                            <a
                                href="/terms"
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            >
                                Terms of Use
                            </a>
                            |
                            <a
                                href="/privacy"
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            >
                                Privacy Policy
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="copyright">
                        <p>
                            &copy; 2018 - MS Air, Inc. |{' '}
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Top_Sellers;
```

And remember to add `key={/*someUnique stuff*/}` inside your map. This can improve react performance.